# No puedo contar cada iteración de un ciclo while mediante un ciclo for en javascript pues arroja undefined

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, while, undefined

En este código Javascript no sé como contar cada vez que un ciclo while se cumple... para empezar no sé si debería ser con un for o modificando de alguna otra manera el mismo while dentro de la condición a cumplir ("salir"). Por consola la variable sumaVuelta arroja undefned y no termino de entender el por qué...

```js
let answer = prompt ("Calculadora! Ingresa la operacion: suma, resta, division o multiplicacion.")
let n;
let vuelta;
let sumaVuelta;


while (answer != "salir" ) {

  for (n = 0; n <= vuelta; n++){
      sumaVuelta = vuelta + 1;
  }

  console.log('Esta es la iteración N° ' + sumaVuelta + ' que se cumple este ciclo');

switch (answer) 
{
    case "suma":
    console.log("suma")

    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) + parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la suma es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la suma es " + number3);

    break;


case "resta":

    console.log("resta")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) - parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la resta es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la resta es " + number3);

    break;



case "division":

    console.log("division")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")

    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)
    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) / parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la division es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la division es " + number3);

    break;


case "multiplicacion":

    console.log("multiplicacion")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) * parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + number3);

    break;

default:

    alert ("Operacion no valida! Ingresar nuevamente")
    console.log ("Operacion no valida! Ingresar nuevamente")

    break;

}

answer = prompt ("Calculadora! Ingresa la operacion: suma, resta, division o multiplicacion.")

}

alert ("Finalizado");
```

Comment: No se exactamente lo que quieres, ni lo que esperas, porque no está claro el enunciado. Nunca inicializas la variable `vuelta` ni `sumaVuelta`, ¿Qué esperas que tenga? No puede tener otra cosa más que `undefined`

Comment: tienes razon @JaimeMenéndez En realidad lo que quiero es contar cada ciclo while que se cumpla hasta que salga de allí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo ocupas una variable `vuelta` para contar las vueltas, que inicializarás en 0 e incrementarás en cada ciclo.

Checa el ejemplo que te adjunto:

```js
let answer = prompt ("Calculadora! Ingresa la operacion: suma, resta, division o multiplicacion.")
let vuelta = 0;


while (answer != "salir" ) {
  vuelta++;

  console.log('Esta es la iteración N° ' + vuelta + ' que se cumple este ciclo');

switch (answer) 
{
    case "suma":
    console.log("suma")

    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) + parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la suma es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la suma es " + number3);

    break;


case "resta":

    console.log("resta")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) - parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la resta es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la resta es " + number3);

    break;



case "division":

    console.log("division")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")

    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)
    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) / parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la division es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la division es " + number3);

    break;


case "multiplicacion":

    console.log("multiplicacion")
    var number1 = prompt ("Ingresa el primer valor")
    console.log("El primer valor es  " + number1)

    var number2 = prompt ("Ingresa el segundo valor")
    console.log("El segundo valor es " + number2)

    var number3 = (parseInt (number1) * parseInt (number2))
    console.log ("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + number3)

    alert ("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + number3);

    break;

default:

    alert ("Operacion no valida! Ingresar nuevamente")
    console.log ("Operacion no valida! Ingresar nuevamente")

    break;

}

answer = prompt ("Calculadora! Ingresa la operacion: suma, resta, division o multiplicacion.")

}

alert ("Finalizado");
```